Interface not being exported as type?
I'm contributing to the open-source package ethers.  For some reason, the CommunityResourceable function was commented out - I'm trying to make it work again.
CommunityResourceable is defined at ethers.js/src.ts/providers
/community.ts (in my fork).
Then, it is exported like this:
export type {
    CommunityResourceable
} from "./community.js";

at src.ts/providers/index.ts
Finally, it is then exported at src.ts/ethers.ts
However, if I install my patched version using git install https://github.com/aaronzshey/ethers.js.git and run
import type { CommunityResourceable } from "ethers"

I get an error that CommunityResourceable is not an export.  Any insights?
Repl.it demo of error here

The export for CommunityResourceable in the src.ts/ethers.ts file is missing, you need to add it there with other exports from ./providers/index.js

I believe I exported CommunityResourceable here: https://github.com/aaronzshey/ethers.js/blob/c8444e1638a8b731ac12ea289d82f0b083427842/src.ts/ethers.ts#L176C38-L176C59
(inside an export type block).  should it go somewhere else?

I think that's where it should be, does it still not work?

Unfortunately it doesn't!  Here's the corresponding GitHub issue: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/4776

When i checked the file ./lib.esm/ethers.d.ts there's still no CommunityResourceable export, same goes with ./lib.esm/ethers.d.ts, did you run the build correctly ?

I did not run the build correctly - I've updated it now.  However, now when I try to run it, I get a load of errors that stop me from testing it.
